# How to parse Mitmdump/Mitmproxy content

Tags: mitmproxy

I am using `mitmdump -dd > outfile` to parse content,which gives me the complete request and response "headers and its body content"(which also removes the junk part of the traffic i.e no certificate's and no compressed data).

But this is making my file really large.How can I just get only the request part of the traffic....

Any advice or link how can this be done??

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The way i handled not exact but similar case is using `-s` flag of mitmdump and get the `flow.request.content` in my script and log it to some log file that will be pretty neat and clean

Here below code might be of some help ( save as t.py and run `mitmdump -s t.py` )

```
from mitmproxy import http
import time,re
import logging

def response(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    flow.response.headers["newheader"] = "foo"

def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    print(flow.request.content)
    request_content = flow.request.content
    # here u get the request content and then log it and use it
```